# regex to get tags previous and next

Tags: html, regex

I have some html in a single string that may or may not have newlines. It could look something like this:

```
<table><tr><th>blah1</th></tr><tr><input class="inputClass"><span>open&lt;pfelclose/>pfelsingle'pfeldouble"pfel</span></input></tr></table>
```

formatted nicely:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>blah1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <input class="inputClass">
      <span>open&lt;pfelclose/>pfelsingle'pfeldouble"pfel</span>
    </input>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to search this string for

```
(open<pfel|close/>pfel|single'pfel|double"pfel)
```

but also get two open tags before and two close tags after. So I'd like to get something like:

```
<input class="inputClass"><span>open&lt;pfelclose/>pfelsingle'pfeldouble"pfel</span></input>
```

I cannot assume that input or span will be there, nor can I assume that there are necessarily two tags before or two tags after.

My attempt seems to always pull the entire start of the string:

```
.*[<]{0,2}?(open<pfel|close/>pfel|single'pfel|double"pfel)[/>]{0,2}?
```

Comment: Don't ever parse html with regex. Use HTML parsers instead.

Comment: I would love to, but all of the html parsers I'm using encode the single quot, double quote and lt gt signs.

Comment: You _want_ `&quot;` to become `"`, right? If not, just replace `"` with `&quot;` after the fact.

Comment: But there is no reason that there aren't other &quot; encodings elsewhere. the regex is useful since I wouldn't have to parse and worry about encoding issues.

Comment: The trouble is that you want to find matching tags (the open and close tags before / after the text you want to find).  Regex *cannot* do this.  It's simply not capable of parsing nested structures like this.  Regex parses regular languages, and this isn't one.

Comment: @IanMcLaird I think your explanation is the best. I managed to get it to work with lookahead/lookbehind, but I do need the ability to get matched tags. I've developed a cheap workaround and stored the offset of the pfel line, parsed the HTML and then reintroduced the pfel line so as to avoid the parser encoding. it's good enough. thanks for your help. feel free to make an answer of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with your situation is that you want to find matching tags (the open and close tags before and after the text you're searching for).  Regex *cannot* do this.  It isn't capable of parsing a nested structure like HTML.  Regex parses regular languages, and HTML isn't one.  Advanced Regex engines can sometimes be coerced into doing *almost* what you're trying to do here, but it's usually more trouble than it's worth.

Your solution in the comments is probably the correct one.  Find what you're looking for with the regex, and then use an HTML parser to get what you need.